# bower does not install dependencies

Tags: javascript, build, frontend, bower

I have following bower.json

```
{
  "name": "name of app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "directory": "public/bower_components",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "less": "~1.6.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "angular": "~1.2.8",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.8",
    "angular-route": "~1.2.8"
  }
}
```

But when I run `bower install` then it does not create `bower_components` under public directory and it does not install dependencies.  Below is screen shot of `bower install` command.

How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

`A custom install location can be set in a .bowerrc file using the directory property. The .bowerrc file should be a sibling of your project's bower.json.`

The custom directory path needs to be set in the .bowerrc file and not bower.json

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma on this line:

```
"bower_components",
```

Delete the comma and it should work.